# How to respond after trying a suggestion?

Tags: support, questions, comments

I asked a question about an error I have been experiencing, posting some code.

Someone responded with an answer, suggesting something to try.

I tried it, and the resulting error gives more information, which may allow the original respondant, or someone else, to diagnose the problem more easily.

My meta-question is, should I post this new error information as a comment, or edit my original question to include it?

Comment: Why not both? The former to continue the dialogue with the user, the latter to give everyone new reading the question the latest info.

Comment: The comment can read simply *"@whomever I've tried that and edited the information into the question"*, and you don't need to put *"EDIT:"* or anything into the question; write it as if it was there all along.